# Program compiling despite using nonexistent members

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-function

```
template <typename T>
void list<T>::copyAll(const list &l)
{
    if(l.isEmpty()) //if the list-to-copy is empty, we're done
    {
        first = last = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *toFollow = l->yhjfrtydfg;
        node *whatever = l.asfqwejfq3fqh23f8hq23r1h23017823r087q1hef;

        while(toFollow != NULL)
        {
            T *newO = new T(*(toFollow->o));
            T here = *newO;
            insertBack(&here);
            toFollow = toFollow->next;
        }
    }
}
```

This program compiles (with the rest of the program), even though the two lines `node *toFollow = l->yhjfrtydfg;` and `node *whatever = l.asfqwejfq3fqh23f8hq23r1h23017823r087q1hef;` are clearly crazy input.  It's strange because any other error is caught.  Any help?

Comment: Is this function used anywhere in the program?

Comment: This is probably because you never call this templetized function and so it is never instantiated.

Comment: it's not really 'input' that is bugus, just funky code.

Comment: Is `copyAll(const list &l)` your code verbatim? `list` does not exist in that form.

Comment: @phresnel: is a member of a class template, the template name is also the injected class name (although I have found that some older compilers won't accept it).

Comment: You *should not* copy `*newO` to a local variable. Storing a pointer to a local variable in your list will cause problems (the dreaded undefined behaviour). Just write `insertBack(newO)`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oops, I've overlooked the fact that it's a member function of the class template called `list`. I've actually assumed Bob was refering to `std::list`. Good catch :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Dependent names" (names used in templates whose meaning depends on the template parameters) are only resolved when the template is instantiated, not when it's defined. If you don't instantiate the template, then it can contain whatever crazy names you like, as long as it's syntactically correct.

Your program would fail to compile if it were instantiated:

```
list<int> l;
l.copyAll(l); // ERROR
```

Comment: @phresnel: Indeed, I did simplify a bit too much.

Answer (score 6):

Names that depend on a template parameter are only resolved once the template is instantiated. Only non-dependent names are resolved in any case.

C++ coined this "two phase lookup", where phase 1 is when it is first parsed, and phase 2 is instantiation time.

E.g.:

```
template <typename T>
void frob() {
    foo = 5; // non-dependent, name must exist at this point
    T bar;
    bar.frobnicate = 7; // dependent, name is looked up upon instantiation

    bar->is->a.funny(T::hing); // dependent, likewise looked up later
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The nonexistent members are the least of your worries- the compiler does not complain because some T might indeed have those members. The fundamental source of your confusion is that the compiler just sees an indentifier like any other- it is only your perception that nobody would use this and clearly no type T has them that makes the input "crazy". It is not crazy at all. It is just an identifier.

```
        T newO = new T(*(toFollow->o));
        insertBack(&newO);
        toFollow = toFollow->next;
```

Is completely and utterly broken. First, you dynamically allocate a T and then *try to construct a stack-allocated T from it*? No T behaves this way. Then you keep a pointer to a stack-allocated object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Suppose T is an int, and *(toFollow->o) = 7.  Then insertBack(&newO) should modify this by adding the new element.  toFollow then moves to the next int to copy.  Can you elaborate on why this is incorrect?